# Can't I debug using my own device when connecting to local web service?

Tags: android, .net, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, iis-express

I have a web service in web api project in a separate solution. I am trying to access that web service from a Xamarin project. I am using my Android phone to debug but I get this error. All of the articles I came across to access web services, use an emulator. Is it because of this that I'm getting this error or have I missed anything?

[image]

**Update 1:**
My code is as follows and the error occurs at line 10 (line containing `using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())`).

```
private async Task<JsonValue> GetNamesAsync()
{
    try
    {
        string  url = "http://{network-ip-address}:{port}/api/Names";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        {
                //Some code here
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**
If I `Step Into` (F11), then after about 2 clicks, the following Dialog Box opens.

[image: Dialog Box]

Comment: This usually appears when trying to step into a Xamarin function (e.g. `base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState)`).  What is the line that should be run when this appears?

Comment: Could you please try `Debug->windows->Exception Settings->tick Common Language Runtime and all it's children options`.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I did as you said. But still getting the same issue. I also updated my question. Please help me if you can. Thank you.

Comment: @JonathanTwite I also updated my question. Please help me if you can. Thank you.

Comment: Do not use `F11` to trying to access the source codes of `GetResponseAsync` as JonathanTwite said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to step into the code:

```
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync()
```

That is, you are trying to debug the `GetResponseAsync()` method in the `HttpWebRequest` class.  The source code for this class has not been loaded into your project (only the compiled `.dll`) and so you cannot step into this line.

Try `F10` to step over this line.

You may now get the same error - however, this time the reason will be different.  As the `GetResponseAsync()` method has been awaited, the programme flow goes back to the method that called `GetNamesAsync()`.  If that call was awaited, and the chain of calls to that method where all awaited back to the `Activity` method (as should be so to not block the UI), the next line of code to execute will be a line of code somewhere in the Xamarin/Android source code that again you don't have access to.

e.g.

```
 1 class MyActivity : Activity
 2 {
 3     // This function is called by the Xamarin/Android systems and is not awaited.
 4     // As it is marked as async, any awaited calls within will pause this function,
 5     // and the application will continue with the function that called this function,
 6     // returning to this function when the awaited call finishes.
 7     // This means the UI is not blocked and is responsive to the user.
 8     public async void OnCreate()
 9     {
10         base.OnCreate();
11         await initialiseAsync(); // awaited - so will return to calling function
12                                  // while waiting for operation to complete.
13
14         // Code here will run after initialiseAsync() has finished.
15     }
16     public async Task initialiseAsync()
17     {
18         JsonValue names = await GetNamesAsync(); // awaited - so will return to Line 11
19                                              // while waiting for operation to complete.
20         
21         // Code here will run after GetNamesAsync() has finished.
22     }
23 }
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I also tried without using asynchronous method (Used `request.GetResponse()` instead). But I get the same error, If I Step Over, then I get an exception as `"The request timed out"`.

Comment: The request timed out error points to your actual problem - the request is not working.  I assume this line actually has the ip and port filled in in your code:  `string  url = "http://{network-ip-address}:{port}/api/Names";`, It is a Get call so you should be able to copy and past that url into Chrome and see if it works.

Comment: I can access _http://{network-ip-address}:{port}_ but not _http://{network-ip-address}:{port}/api/Names_. I get a _HTTP 404 error_

Comment: Looks like your routing is incorrect. Check the Web API source code, especially `[Route("api/...")]` attributes on the `Controller` method, or if not set there, the default route configuration set in `App_Start\WebApiConfig`.  This may be case sensitive (I can't remember).

Comment: Thank you for the help. Got it to work at last. I also have missed to configure IIS to allow external requests.